# Why does the Canonical bar on meta omit Insights and Juju?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

Canonical navigation bar, as seen on main Ask Ubuntu site:

[image: main]

Canonical navigation bar, as seen here on meta:

[image: meta]

Or just look at the top of your screen...  Two items are missing: Insights and Juju.

Comment: It looks normal to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad. I forgot to update meta when I did the Ubuntu nav bag changes on the main site.